# CSS Only Approach to position nested cells horisontally

Tags: html, css

I have a list of objects and would like to implement the following CSS-only approach of  positioning scheme:

[image]

This will be a dynamically populated list and it is important for us to "group" bigger cells that consist of 4 small cells (2x2, as it is shown).
I've tried implementations based on clearing the floats after every 4-th element but did not succeed. The solution I believe will be to successfully manage to create a bigger cell that consists of 4 small ones and which is floated left.
Any small cell will be based on a fixed width/height, yes (say, width:100px; height:100px;). And the solution will have to be IE8+

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .smallCell {
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 5px;
            background-color: #efefef;
            border: 1px solid #f00;
        }
        .smallCell:nth-of-type(5n){
            background-color: #f0f;
            float: left;
            clear: both;
        }
        .smallCellRow {
            width: 240px;
            height: 120px;
            margin: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #0f0;
        }
        .mainCont {
            float: left;
            height: 280px;
            max-height: 280px;
            background-color: #ffcfbf;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mainCont">
        <div class="smallCell">1</div>
        <div class="smallCell">2</div>
        <div class="smallCell">3</div>
        <div class="smallCell">4</div>
        <div class="smallCell">5</div>
        <div class="smallCell">6</div>
        <div class="smallCell">7</div>
        <div class="smallCell">8</div>      
    </div>
</body>
```

Any assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: What code are you expecting? What do you have till now?

Comment: Does this need to work on IE < 9?

Comment: Tell us about the dimensions of each element. Does each element have a fixed width and height?

Comment: Mark, the dimensions will be fixed width and height, yes. Just edited my initial post, sorry for missing to clarify that

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this and improve on it:

---

#### Using Floats

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="group">
        <div class="cell">1</div>
        <div class="cell">2</div>
        <div class="cell">3</div>
        <div class="cell">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="cell">1</div>
        <div class="cell">2</div>
        <div class="cell">3</div>
        <div class="cell">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="cell">1</div>
        <div class="cell">2</div>
        <div class="cell">3</div>
        <div class="cell">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="cell">1</div>
        <div class="cell">2</div>
        <div class="cell">3</div>
        <div class="cell">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {width: 500px; overflow: hidden;}
.group {width: 48%; float: left;}
.cell {width: 48%; float: left; text-align: center; line-height: 100px; background: #09f; border: 1px solid #ccc;}
```

---

#### Without Floats

**CSS**

```
.wrap {width: 500px; overflow: hidden;}
.group {width: 48%; display: inline-block;}
.cell {width: 48%; display: inline-block; text-align: center; line-height: 100px; background: #09f; border: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 2px 0 0;}
```

#### Preview

**Floated**

[image]

**Inline-Block**

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/Gmy89/ (Floated)

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/Gmy89/1/ (Inline-Block)

Comment: Clean and simple. Note: The key to horizontally neighboring divs is float.

Comment: @Domi Can also be achieved without using float! :) I will put that too.

Comment: The snippets provided are fine, but I think you guys miss one essential fact - the list will be dynamically populated, so if you use this grouping, how will any 5-th element know that it should start a new "big cell" area?
I believe dynamically we will add only <div class="cell">...</div> and in terms of CSS once the 2x2 cell is full, a new one will have to be triggered, float left-ed to the previous one. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @DimiterDimitrov It is possible. Just keep a counter. :) As simple as that, or there are 100s of JavaScript snippets that convert the list to this way, and doesn't break on even AJAX Calls. :) What say?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: Please refer to the title of the post: I need a CSS only solution and that's why I posted the question here. I do know how to achieve the desired markup via static HTML, I do know how to use JS to achieve that too, the point is IS THERE a CSS ONLY solution? I mean, Once I define a master container and a bigger cell (2x2), any small cell to automatically detect IF it can fit any 2x2 cell, otherwise just start a new 2x2 cell.
Guys, thanks for your feedback, but please refer to the title of the post. It is essential.

Answer (score 1):

One posibility is to keep the first cell of the group inline-block, but with and over-size, and manage the others thru relative positioning (and some tricks with margins).

I have done the demo with smaller dimensions, to make it easier to play with it.

The main advantage is that you don't need to manage anything in the HTML.

You will be using nth-child, so you will need polyfill for IE8. (But anyway, in your code there are  already nth-childs)

CSS

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid 1px gray;
}

.container div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
.container div:nth-child(4n+1) {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.container div:nth-child(4n+2) {
    position: relative;
    left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}

.container div:nth-child(4n+3) {
    position: relative;
    left: -46px;
    top: 20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}

.container div:nth-child(4n) {
    position: relative;
    left: -26px;
    top: 20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/hRnSR/)

Comment: Hah, that sounds like a working piece of code, awesome! And really pretty simple, thanks Vals!!!

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul class=row>
    <li>
        <ul class=grid>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class=grid>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    min-width: 80px;
    min-height: 80px;
}

.grid > li:nth-child(3) {
    clear: both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MyQqE/1/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Mark.
Yes, it works, can you please clarify how I will be able to fill that list dynamically? If a 5-th cell arrives, how will it realize if the 2x2 is already full and create a new one? I mean CSS only, if it is about JS, I know how to solve my issue and it is almost trivial.

Comment: It can't be done without JS. Once you float the 4th item down to the next line, you can't go back up without absolute positioning. Once you start absolutely positioning items you will have to do it over and over. This isn't practical and can't be done dynamically without JS.

Comment: Thanks Mark, 
I did think it cannot be done without JS but wanted to get other points of view too. So, will shoot further with a few lines of JS code.
Much appreciated!